# How do I insert a SQL Server result multiple times in a live word document using VB

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-office, ms-word

Ok, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to take a mail merge, use that info to make MS SQL calls and get strings back in a word document. I'm guessing VB but I have no VB experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do a mail merge using data from SQL Server then (in Word 2003 anyway) there's an option on step 3 of the mail merge wizard:

Use an existing list > Browse > New SQL Server connection

If you want to take the results of a mail merge from some other data source and then query SQL Server with those results then you're going to need VBA. As well as working out how to manipulate data in the Word object model, you're going to need something like [ActiveX Data Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681025(VS.85).aspx) (ADO) for the database queries